# Better way to check multiple OR condition within single if statement in javascript

Tags: javascript

Is it possible to further simplify the following `javascript` statement. the requirement is if any input is negative it should execute the statement inside if block. i am wondering if i can avoid `< 0` multiple times and just use once

```
    if (Number(cash.value) < 0 || Number(cheque.value) < 0 || Number(charge.value) < 0 || Number(card.value) < 0) {
doSomething();
}
```

i simplified to this logic

```
if ((Number(Cash.value) || Number(Cheque.value) || Number(Charge.value) || Number(Card.value)) < 0)
```

but it does not work and does not meet requirement. the above logic works but there is duplication of <0 logic

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simplify removing for example `Number()` - the + sign turns strings holding a number into an actual number, and we can still use the faster logic operands:

```
if (+cash.value < 0 || +cheque.value < 0 || +charge.value < 0 || +card.value) < 0) {
  doSomething();
}
```

As to the problem with the second line -

The reason this line doesn't work (besides from a possible typo, as JavaScript is case-sensitive):

```
if ((Number(Cash.value) || Number(Cheque.value) || Number(Charge.value) || Number(Card.value)) < 0)
```

is that this `Number(Cash.value)` is converted into a boolean value, ie. if the value is 0 then false, anything else will convert to true. So if the numbers are non-0, plus or minus, they will pass through, except the last test which only passes as intended. Each value has to be tested individually.

Word of advice: unless you need to check numerous values in parallel, avoid using arrays (whether its ES6 or earlier). This is significantly slower than doing boolean checks directly, especially in older browsers which parses and have no optimization of JavaScript.

Comment: @K3N. would that work in older IE version for example IE 7.0

Comment: @raja it's also significantly faster than pushing values to an array and the iterate over it. If you only have a few values to compare against, use plain logical operands as here.

Comment: @K3N. many thanks . does it work reversely so if values are positive and no negative or combination of both will it still convert to number

Comment: @raja, yes, it will take any number provided it is in a valid format (see [this example](https://jsfiddle.net/epistemex/gt4eorb4/)).

Answer (score 6):

You can try to do like this

```
var numbers = [Cash.value, Cheque.value, Charge.value, Card.value];

if(numbers.some(value => Number(value) < 0)){
   doSomething();
}
```

For Example, is working in **ES6**

```js
var numbers = [11, 12, -1,-7];

if(numbers.some(value => value < 0)){
   console.log('Found !!!');
}
```

For under **IE 9**, you can write a function and use

```js
function anyNegative(numbers){
  for(var i = 0; i < numbers.length; i++){
     if(numbers[i] < 0){
        return true;
     }
  }
  
  return false;
}

var numbers = [11, 12, -1,-7];

if(anyNegative(numbers)){
     console.log('Found !!!');
}
```

Comment: would that work in older version of IE for example IE 7 and above

Comment: No, for IE 9 and newer versions. Updated

Comment: @3355307 if this helps you, you can mark as correct and help others to find it easily

Answer (score 0):

How about :

```
if([Cash,Cheque,Charge,Card].some(obj => Number(obj.value) < 0)) {
    doSomething();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Or have it as a function, in case you need it in more places. It takes N number of inputs to verify

https://jsfiddle.net/2L1L7ncj/

```
function isAnyArgumentNegative(){
    var args = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments);
  return args.some(function(a){
    return Number(a) < 0;
  });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think, not really.

Your second statement will not work, because you are essentially checking all the values - except for the last one - to be truthy, and then only the last one for being negative.

If you want to make the code more readable, you might add a helper function:

```
function isNegative(value) {
  return Number(value) < 0;
}
```

And then use that in your if statements.

Technically you could make a function like this:

```
function atLeastOneNegative() {
  for (var i = 0; i < arguments.length; i++) {
    if (Number(i) < 0) return true;
 } 

  return false;
}
```

But I think the first option would give nicer code.